# How to properly initiate an OAuth flow for Gmail Watch?

Tags: firebase, gmail-api

I'm trying to initiate Gmail Watch on behalf of my site's users and also get the messages according to what historyId I get on the corresponding PubSub Topic.
I have GCP + Firebase on the backend and Angular 7 in the frontend.
I face two problems here:

1. Doing this on the frontend seems the right way, with grantOfflineAccess, since it asks nicely on the consent screen for the required Modify scope. However, what I get back is an auth code, and I can't find out how to get access and refresh tokens from it, and use it in the backend Cloud Functions python part.
2. If I try this on the backend (which works), I have to initiate the flow from python, send the redirect to Angular and pop-up the consent url there. This already seems bad, since the consent screen does not say anything about what you're granting. Then I need a redirect url, which can't be a Cloud Functions url, because I can't whitelist it (can verify the domain), so it is now handled on the Angular side and sent back. Ie. the my oauth redirect is handled in the frontend, which also doesn't seem the right way.

Could you please advise on how to do this properly?

Thanks!